# Angular2 forms - access value in ngIf

Tags: forms, angular

I have a`<select #type >`. Now I need to reference the value of this select later on in the template inside a ngIf, but how can I do so?

Tried `*ngIf='type.value!="Category"'` and it doesn't seem to do the trick..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you bind the select to your model and then reference the model element?

```
<select [(ngModel)]="type">
  <!-- Options -->
</select>
<div *ngIf="type !== 'Category'">
</div>
```